# Session value is overriding even using different browser

Tags: asp.net, session-state, vps, iis-8

I am using session to store user name in my website. I logged in using three different user's credential in three different browsers- IE, firefox and chrome. After doing some work, I found that session is overriding values between browsers. Did any body faced such problems. On localhost it is working fine. I am using VPS to host my website and facing problem there. Please help.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. You need to be much more specific about what you're doing, what the problem is, what code you're using and how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AntP Let say I logged in as ABC in firefox browser and store this value in Session["user"]. Now I logged in as XYZ in IE browser. Session["user"] value is replaced by XYZ. It should not happen as it will break Session state logic. Working fine at localhost but not in live environment. I have my own VPS and hosted my site there.

Comment: Can anybody answer this question. It is really opposing the session concept. Session is sharing between different browsers(IE, Mozilla)